# Implemented Leetcode 2. add two numbers by C

Tags: c

The topic is [Add two numbers](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/).

There is my code:

```
int valueDecoder(struct ListNode *link)
{
    int sum = 0, exponent = 0;
    while (link)
    {
        sum += link->val * pow(10, exponent);
        exponent++;
        link = link->next;
    }
    return (sum);
}

struct ListNode *valueEncoder(int val1, int val2)
{
    struct ListNode *tempNode, *currentLink, *rootLink;
    currentLink = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    rootLink = currentLink;
    int sum = val1 + val2;
    while (sum)
    {
        tempNode = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
        tempNode->val = sum % 10;
        sum = (sum - tempNode->val) / 10;
        currentLink->next = tempNode;
        currentLink = currentLink->next;
    }
    tempNode->next = NULL;
    currentLink = rootLink->next;
    free(rootLink);
    return currentLink;
}

struct ListNode *addTwoNumbers(struct ListNode *l1, struct ListNode *l2)
{
    return (valueEncoder(valueDecoder(l1), valueDecoder(l2)));
}
```

I want to translate 2 inputed links to decimal values, and then tranlate the sum of the two values
to linklist.
However, I encounter the problem below:

[image]

How could I resolve thin problem by my idea?
Thanks！

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add text messages as text to your question instead of images. Also your error message contains a line number. Which is that in your code?

Comment: What does "inputed link" mean? Where and how do you get any input? What input do you get? Or do you mean the pointers you are get as parameter to `addTwoNumbers`?

Comment: Please read [How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. a compileable code that reproduces your problem. We cannot see what data you provide to your function and if that is valid. Please also add your input and expected output. Together any output you get before your runtime error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read in the problem description, the biggest possible inputted numbers will be up to 100 digits. Since you're storing the resulting sum in an int, that won't work, because an int can't handle numbers that big.

What you should do instead is calculate the result one digit add a time. You'd start at the first two digits add them up. If the result is bigger than ten save the carry and subtract ten. Than add this result to the resulting linked list. Repeat with the next two digits. It's a bit like how you would add actual decimal numbers on paper yourself.

This is the code for that (I originally wrote this in C++, so there could be some mistakes):

```
struct ListNode* addTwoNumbers(struct ListNode* l1, struct ListNode* l2) {
        struct ListNode n;
        bool carry = false;
        bool firstit = true;
        for (struct ListNode *c1 = l1, *c2 = l2, *c = &n;; c = c->next, firstit = false) {
            int sum = carry;
            if (c1) {
                sum += c1->val;
                c1 = c1->next;
                carry = true;
            }
            if (c2) {
                sum += c2->val;
                c2 = c2->next;
                carry = true;
            }
            if (!(carry || firstit)) break;

            carry = sum > 9;
            if (carry) sum -= 10;

            c->next = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
            c->next->next = NULL;
            c->next->val = sum;
        }

        return n.next;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I had known what's wrong with my idea.